# kubectl, information about node from inside docker

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

i am running ipyparallel in an kube cluster. I have several pods running on one node which is fine. But for my computation i want to help ipyparallel in loadbalancing by choosing pods evenly over all nodes. 
Is there a way to get this information from inside the pods/docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Kubernetes Service which does round-robin loadbalancing.
If you need the IP addresses, you could do a DNS A- or SRV-Records lookup and get all IPs of all running instances: http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/dns/